# Allow user to write dynamic blog page with image and text

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to build a blog page, that the users enter text and drag images anywhere on the blog/page, and then they could save it.

I need it to look something like:

[image]

Do you know how to make something like that? I tried to look over the web, and could't find how to make it, neither open source project.

thx (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the drag & drop part is not mandatory I would use a **WYSIWYG** editor to let the user write the contents they want and include images. Well, in your case maybe 2 editors, one for the subject and another one for the content.

In google you can find lots of them like https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor and https://www.tinymce.com/

In some of them (like the tinymce one) you can choose which options you let the user use from all the options they provide. I used it some years ago in a platform to create and send bunch of emails to subscribed users. And the email contents were created in a similar way at what you have just described.